# Software center empty and no unistall button in dash

Tags: software-center, unity-dash

I have these two problems [image: one screenshot]

[image: two screenshot]

which I assume are related.
What happens is that suddenly all the apps in software center are gone and in dash there is no 'uninstall' button, only the 'launch' one

Comment: can you convert this messages in english??

Comment: Convert what? What happens is that suddenly all the apps in software center are gone and in dash there is no 'uninstall' button, only the 'launch' one

Comment: There isn't anything to convert. The only things that matter in the images are the lack of apps in the first and unistall button in the second

Comment: @oneuseaccount- add the "what happens" para to question

Comment: I think that should be understandable seeing the title and the images, but anyway.

Comment: I cannot understand the language

Comment: Have you tried sudo apt-get update ?

Comment: Yes, I've tried it but it hasn't solved anything

Comment: Possible duplicate of [New "Ubuntu Software" not working (16.04)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/760275/new-ubuntu-software-not-working-16-04)

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this problem by reinstallation of software-center something like that:

```
$ sudo apt-get purge software-center
$ sudo apt-get autoremove -y
$ sudo apt-get clean -y
$ sudo apt-get install software-center
```