# New "Ubuntu Software" not working (16.04)

Tags: software-center, 16.04

After upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04, I tried to use the new software center that came along with it, but I found it to have a few issues. One, it didn't detect all the applications I had previously installed and two, whenever I tried installing new software with it, a new icon on the launcher (saying "Waiting to Install") appears, but no progress is made and the icon is stuck on the launcher.

However, I don't encounter any of these issues in the older Software Center. Does anybody know why this may be?

[image]

Comment: This is what happens when Canonical decides to use the GNOME 3.20 version of GNOME software rather than a GNOME 3.18 version...

Comment: duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/761210/16-04-cannot-install-anything-from-ubuntu-software-center

Answer (score 11):

Try installing the old software-center from  the commandline:

```
sudo apt install software-center
```

Or try installing synaptic

```
sudo apt install synaptic
```

Comment: I faced the same problem today on 16.04.1 LTS.  The system prompt on terminal, to install 'software-center' worked fine for me.

Comment: Me too had the same problem, 'Ubuntu Software' is not working in 16.04 but 'Ubuntu Software Center' is working perfectly fine.

Comment: Your suggestion worked @jringoot, I just `sudo apt-get intall software-center`

Answer (score 4):

I resolved this same issue using 'check for updates' thru the 'About this Computer'-->'Details' menu found thru the top right menu area of the desktop.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Be aware that we value high-quality content here, so a better explanation (or wording) would fit better.

Comment: This worked for me too. After doing "Check for Updates", Ubuntu Software began working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to download and install the old Software Center from the new Software Center. Just type in the name in the new Software Center, find it and use it.