# 16.04 Cannot install anything from Ubuntu Software center

Tags: 16.04, package-management, software-installation, gnome-software

Whenever I double click a deb file, it'd be opened in software center. However, when I click "install" button, it'd change to "installing" for a second but then turn back to "install" and nothing happens. It also says "This software comes from a 3rd party and may contain non-free components" at the bottom. I have enabled all the options in Software & Updates and also tried reinstalling software center but nothing helped.

Comment: This is a bug, please add this as "also effects" here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-software/+bug/1573206

Comment: @MarkKirby i cannot believe they should release the official version without fixing such simple bugs

Comment: Seems to affect alot of people too. Issue is in Gnome software, that replaced the software center in 16.04, hopefully. if people sign the bug report they will patchy it fast.

Comment: It looks like they've released a fix for this according to launchpad but I still am having this issue after doing a software update.

Comment: @IanLantzy how did you update it?

Comment: Using the Software Updater program and 'sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade'

Comment: there are several issues here , bugs in gnome software center and the retirement of sha1 from the APT system in favour of SHA256 or SHA512.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

If you want to install programs via .deb files, I suggest to use Gdebi.

It's a lightweight application that is better at installing .deb packages, and is quicker as well. If there are dependencies, it notifies that as well.

In the terminal, type:

```
sudo apt install gdebi
```

You can right click on .deb file and select to open it with Gdebi.

If you like Gdeb, you can make it default to have it open all the .deb files in future.

Read this: http://itsfoss.com/gdebi-default-ubuntu-software-center/

Answer (score 12):

If you need to install software that is not in the repositories, and the Software Center is not working, there is an alternative but it requires the terminal.
You must first navigate to the folder where you downloaded the debian package, which is usually in the 'Downloads' folder.

You can open the terminal from that folder by right-clicking and pressing "Open Terminal", or you can navigate to it via the Terminal by:

```
cd /path/to/folder
```

After that you just run this command:

```
sudo dpkg -i nameofpackage.deb
```

Comment: What I do not like about this method is that, for me at least, the application's icon won't appear in Dash.

Comment: Some applications do show in dash.  At least they did for me.  That's weird.

Comment: Yeah I know, I thought it was just the burden of using the CLI, that it was a feature of the software center so to say. Now I'm not so sure. I might need to investigate.

Comment: All this does is open the software center and continues to not work

Comment: This should not run the software center at all.

Answer (score 1):

This is not specifically a bug in ubuntu its an APT thing . Its just very unfortunate timing for the 16.04 release that the SHA1 has is being retired. SHA1 is used by the APT system extensively to checksum packages , its being deprecated in favour of SHA256 or SHA512 which is safer.

If you notice a package is not working then please contact the repo maintainer and ask them to update their SHA implementation.

Debians writeup of effected repos and how to update
https://wiki.debian.org/Teams/Apt/Sha1Removal

How and why the apt system secures its packages and repositories 
https://wiki.debian.org/SecureApt

As suggested by others the work around is to manually download the file and verify it yourself before installing with a non repository aware tool like dpkg or gdebi.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to install a software you have two options

1. using Software Center
2. using terminal

If you are facing some problem with first method you can go for second method.

1. Add PPA using following command

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:<ppa_name>
   ```

   If the above command does not work, try following command

   ```
   sudo -E add-apt-repository ppa:<ppa_name>
   ```
2. Then write following command:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```

   then

   ```
   sudo apt-get install <software-name>
   ```