# Cannot install external applications using the Ubuntu software center in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: software-center, 16.04

I have upgraded 14.04 to 16.04 and I have found some problems while instaling external software - deb packages downloaded.

More precisely Debian files do not install using the ubuntu software centre. Does anybody know how can I resolve this issue? If I install packages already in the software center they do install correctly, but if they are .deb files that I have downloaded from the internet they do not install.

Comment: This is a high priority bug which should be fixed soon. In the meantime, use GDebi or dpkg.

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-software/+bug/1573206 - click the "this affects me".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [16.04 Cannot install anything from Ubuntu Software center](http://askubuntu.com/questions/761210/16-04-cannot-install-anything-from-ubuntu-software-center)