# Mendeley desktop won't work on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, mendeley

I've been trying to install [Mendeley](https://www.mendeley.com/download-mendeley-desktop/) on ubuntu 16.04. I followed the installation guide on their website but it simply doesn't start. The icon appears when I run it and in 3 seconds it disappears. Any thoughts?

Output of running `mendeleydesktop` in terminal

```
Unable to use Qt libraries in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu. Some components are missing:
 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtWebKit.so.4 To run Mendeley Desktop you may need to install the QtWebKit and QtSvg packages provided by your Linux distribution. Using bundled SSL runtime libraries /usr/bin/../../opt/mendeleydesktop/bin/mendeleydesktop: error while loading shared libraries: libgstapp-0.10.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Could you please add the project URL and the package-name to your original post (by editing it). i can't find any package called mendeley in the 16.04 repository. I assume you are talking about https://www.mendeley.com/

Comment: If an application seems to crash it often helps to start it from a terminal/commandline. The advantage might be that it outputs some error code or similar which might be a good starting point on the search for a solution.

Comment: It starts here properly on 16.04 and displays a login dialog with register and signin option.

Comment: Works for me too on gnome-1604, open a terminal and run `mendeleydesktop` and add any and all output to the question.

Comment: Instructions at https://www.mendeley.com/download-mendeley-desktop/ubuntu/instructions/ work for me on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: So I get this when I run the command from the terminal: Unable to use Qt libraries in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu. Some components are missing:
 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtWebKit.so.4
To run Mendeley Desktop you may need to install the QtWebKit and QtSvg packages provided by your Linux distribution.
Using bundled SSL runtime libraries
/usr/bin/../../opt/mendeleydesktop/bin/mendeleydesktop: error while loading shared libraries: libgstapp-0.10.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: Add output to the question please, it is hard to read in comments, I did it for you this time.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Open a terminal and run

```
sudo apt-get install libqtsvg4-perl libqtwebkit4
```

I had this exact error and after Mark Kirby's answer I still had the problem. After running the above, now Mendeley launches and syncs all my data (yeah!).

What I don't know is if it was just what I wrote above or if you need this and also Mark Kirby's answer both.

Source of answer: http://ubuntuforum-br.org/index.php?topic=120046.0

Comment: I was able to get it working using only your command without using the one from Mark Kirby's answer.

Comment: @aconkey Thanks for posting this. I'm sure it will help someone in the future.

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be missing some dependencies `qtwebkit` and `qtsvg`

Open a terminal and run

```
sudo apt install qt4-dev-tools
```

Now try to run it again.

Comment: got this: 'libqt5webkit5 is already the newest version'

Comment: Try this updated version.

Comment: I have the exact same error as the OP. This did not fix it. It did install the tools but the error I get is still the same (as in the question). Any other ideas?

Comment: I took this from stack overflow in case this did not work, run `sudo apt-get install libgstreamer0.10-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev` @John Same error but different app http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26869830/genymotion-error-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts

Comment: Thanks @MarkKirby. After applying my answer it's working. I'm not sure if your extra solution would have also done the trick (also like the OP, I'm quite the newbie).

Comment: Glad it worked at @John this was a pain of a question to get fixed, many solutions did not work, it is good to have multiple solutions to cover different situations :)

Answer (score 1):

To install the minimum requirements on Ubuntu 16.04 follow:

```
sudo apt-get install libqtwebkit4 libqt4-svg
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment on the answer because I don't have enough reputation points. I just wanted to say that the answer didn't work for me but installing gdebi

```
sudo apt install gdebi
```

from [16.04 Cannot install anything from Ubuntu Software center](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761210/16-04-cannot-install-anything-from-ubuntu-software-center) and installing through gdebi by right clicking the .deb file and opening with gdebi worked fine.

Also if you mess up the install (like I did) you can re-install using gdebi.