# Mendeley Desktop won't install on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: mendeley

Mendeley Desktop simply fails to install on Ubuntu 16.04. I have followed all the instructions [here](https://www.mendeley.com/download-mendeley-desktop/ubuntu/instructions/). Ubuntu software launches when I click the download and I hit "Install" but then nothing happens.

Another poster [also had trouble](https://askubuntu.com/questions/780224/mendeley-desktop-wont-work-on-ubuntu-16-04) with Mendeley and 16.04. As suggested by answers there, I ran

```
sudo apt-get install libqtsvg4-perl libqtwebkit4
```

and

```
sudo apt install qt4-dev-tools
```

to no avail. When I type

```
mendeleydesktop
```

in the terminal, the output is:

```
mendeleydesktop: command not found
```

Comment: This is a helpful guide for the tech-users (researchers like me). https://techooid.com/install-mendeley-on-ubuntu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just installed mendeley downloading te package directly from the website https://www.mendeley.com/download-mendeley-desktop/ubuntu/instructions/ , and open it with the software installation, or install it following  the installation steps for a Debian package. It works for me.

Comment: They've changed the instructions at that link, thanks for alerting me to it! It's working now :)