# Software Center vs. dpkg

Tags: 16.04, software-center, dpkg, deb

I am testing .deb package I created on ubuntu 16.04, and it seems that when I am using `dpkg -i` - the installation goes well, but when I am using the double-click to install it with "Ubuntu Software" it does copy the files but doesn't run some of the commands in the installation scripts.

The installation is going well, it asks me for a password, and eventually the button label turns to "Remove".

I guess it is a permission issue...
How can I get the logs of Ubuntu Software?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://askubuntu.com/questions/761210/16-04-cannot-install-anything-from-ubuntu-software-center

Comment: The installation is not the issue, just the .deb scripts (post install) ...

Comment: Try to run `ubuntu-software` in terminal and see if the output when trying to install the deb is any  use.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [16.04 Cannot install anything from Ubuntu Software center](http://askubuntu.com/questions/761210/16-04-cannot-install-anything-from-ubuntu-software-center)