# Can't install software from Ubuntu Software

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, gnome-software

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit. Every time I want to install software using the Ubuntu Software or the .deb package, it won't finish installing.

[image: won't finish installing]

I tried the solution here: [16.04 Cannot install anything from Ubuntu Software center](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761210/16-04-cannot-install-anything-from-ubuntu-software-center?newreg=3bcc099226564f4c8289ba84aefdc3cc), but it doesn't resolve my problem.

Comment: Try installing via apt command and post output

Comment: 100% agreed with Danial. Installing via command line will let you/us know of any errors. If you don't know how to, just open a terminal, and type: sudo apt install virtualbox

Answer (score 2):

There are many possible reasons why Ubuntu Software (a.k.a. gnome-software) is not working for you. I was having issues with it myself.

1. Firstly, since you started but were not able to complete installs, you probably have an install queue that you need to clear.

   - Make sure Ubuntu Software (gnome-software) is not running. Before making any changes, you want to backup the gnome-software folder that lives in your home directory, which holds the install queue. In Terminal or a CLI:

     ```
     cp -r ~/.local/share/gnome-software ~/.local/share/gnome-software-BAK
     ```
   - Clear the install queue

     ```
     rm ~/.local/share/gnome-software/install-queue
     ```
   - Reopen Ubuntu Software (either from launcher or by typing
     `gnome-software` into the command line)
   - If the above doesn't work, you could also try removing your home folder's gnome-software directory altogether. Quit Ubuntu Software, then enter:

     ```
     rm -r ~/.local/share/gnome-software
     ```
   - Restart Ubuntu Software. If that did not help, You can always undo the removal of the gnome-software folder and restore the backup:

     ```
     rm -r ~/.local/share/gnome-software && mv ~/.local/share/gnome-software-BAK ~/.local/share/gnome-software
     ```
2. You could also be having problems because you need to run an upgrade.

   - In Terminal, enter:

     ```
     sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`
     ```
   - Then restart your computer.
3. Your sources list might be causing issues for you. My problems with Ubuntu Software were resolved by fully removing PPA's that I thought I had gotten rid of using `add-apt-repository --remove`, which did not get rid of their .list files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`, nor did it get rid of their keyrings in `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/`. If the software you're trying to install is from a PPA, you could still try cleaning out other PPA's, as these may be slowing down Ubuntu Software. There are known issues with the PPA associated with google-chrome-stable, for example.

   - Edit the list (`/etc/apt/sources.list`) itself. It's much speedier to do it completely from command line: `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list` then `sudo apt-get update`. You can also do this in the Software and Updates GUI (run from launcher or open in command line with `software-properties-gtk`), but it seems to take so much longer to do the updating step when I use the GUI. I can add steps for doing it this way if you want, though.
   - If you already know the names of the PPA's you want to remove then you can get rid of them one by one using the command: `sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:<repo>/<subdirectory>`. Note: There's also `ppa-purge`, which I didn't want to use because it downgrades packages associated with the PPA to versions available in repositories, and I wasn't sure if this would affect the programs I had installed, as the programs themselves were not the problem.
   - After editing `sources.list`, you may find (like I did) that old PPA's are still showing up in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` (a directory containing `.list` files of each PPA), and their keyrings were still in `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d`.

     You can check this yourself by entering the command:

     ```
     ls -lR /etc/apt/ | grep -v '~'
     ```
   - Then you can get a list of the .list files in sources.list.d and remove them one by one:

     ```
     ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d
     sudo rm -i /etc/apt/sources.list.d/<PPAName>.list
     sudo apt-get update
     ```
   - To remove the keys:

     ```
     sudo apt-key list
     sudo apt-key del <KEY_ID>
     sudo apt-get update
     ```

After this, Ubuntu Software was actually functioning, hope this helps you!

There's also the possibility you need to do a "deeper" version of sudo apt-get upgrade:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

and restart.